# want persons that are in all four deparments

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The problem is when I run the code it checks to see if any person has been in department 1 then stops but only want persons that have been in all four departments

```
SELECT
    p.person_id AS ID,
    CONCAT(p.firstname, " ", p.surname) AS 'Employee Name'
FROM
    person AS p, 
    allocation_to_department AS ad
WHERE
    ad.person_id = p.person_id
    AND ad.department_id= ('1,2,3,4')
```

Comment: " it checks to see if any person has been in department 1 then stops" ...no, it checks if a person is in department 1 OR department 2 OR department 3 OR department 4. That's what `IN` does - it's just a short way of writing lots of ORs, which you can read about in any SQL manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an aggregate query that will return the persons that belong to all 4 departments (id 1 to 4):

```
SELECT
    p.person_id AS ID,
    CONCAT(p.firstname, " ", p.surname) AS 'Employee Name'
FROM
     person AS p
     INNER JOIN allocation_to_department AS ad
         ON ad.person_id = p.person_id          
GROUP BY 
    p.person_id, 
    p.first_name, 
    p.surname
HAVING 
    MAX(ad.department_id = 1) = 1
    MAX(ad.department_id = 2) = 1
    MAX(ad.department_id = 3) = 1
    MAX(ad.department_id = 4) = 1
```

Another solution would to be use an `IN` clause and `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT
    p.person_id AS ID,
    CONCAT(p.firstname, " ", p.surname) AS 'Employee Name'
FROM
     person AS p
     INNER JOIN allocation_to_department AS ad
         ON ad.person_id = p.person_id
         AND ad.department_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY 
    p.person_id, 
    p.first_name, 
    p.surname
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT ad.department_id) = 4
```

NB: always use *explicit* `JOIN`s instead of old-school, *implicit* joins. I modified the queries accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by grouping the joined tables and select only the rows that have all 4 `department_id`s:

```
SELECT
  p.person_id AS ID,
  CONCAT(p.firstname, ' ', p.surname) AS `Employee Name`
FROM person AS p inner join allocation_to_department AS ad
on ad.person_id = p.person_id 
where ad.department_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by ID, `Employee Name`
having count(*) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT p.person_id AS ID, CONCAT(p.firstname, " ", p.surname) AS 'Employee Name'
FROM person AS p, allocation_to_department AS ad
WHERE
ad.person_id = p.person_id 
AND
ad.department_id in (1,2,3,4)
```